# Why are my wxTreeListCtrl column widths always wrong?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to display multiple columns with a wxTreeListCtrl. I'm using wxWidgets 3.0.5 and developing with GTK, although I'm intending to use this code in OSX and Windows.

The screenshot below shows what I'm seeing (the application is a file browser, in case that's not obvious). The first column, `Filename`, is always sized to the width of the tree view. The other two columns are pushed off the right; you can see the scroll bar.

[image: screenshot]

If I manually resize the window, the two columns pop into view, which makes me feel that the tree view hasn't been laid out properly, but the right-hand column's manually set width is always ignored and as I continue to resize the window it gradually gets larger and larger.

I've tried manually setting and getting the column widths, and it appears that the tree view control is mostly ignoring the numbers I give it --- if I call `SetColumnWidth(...)` and then `GetColumnWidth(...)` immediately afterwards, I get either 0 or an incorrect number.

The actual code is trivial --- this is all generated with wxformbuilder, so I'd expect it to work:

```
    browserTree = new wxTreeListCtrl( browsePanel, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTL_MULTIPLE|wxBORDER_THEME );
    browserTree->AppendColumn( wxT("Filename"), wxCOL_WIDTH_DEFAULT, wxALIGN_LEFT, 0 );
    browserTree->AppendColumn( wxT("Size"), 100, wxALIGN_RIGHT, 0 );
    browserTree->AppendColumn( wxT("Mode"), 100, wxALIGN_LEFT, 0 );
```

(I should add that this behaviour manifests *in the wxformbuilder GUI viewer*, too.)

The main thing which makes me suspicious is that the widget hierarchy is pretty complex, so it's possible one of the parents is doing something to upset the tree view, but I've tried moving the tree view into a new box sizer in a new frame and exactly the same thing happens there. But there's a screenshot of the hierarchy below in case that helps.

I have found some very old bugs describing this behaviour (e.g. this one: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/17476) but they're all *really* old and have been fixed anyway. If this were a real bug I'd expect to see a lot more complaints, as it makes the widget essentially unusable; therefore, this must be something I'm doing wrong, probably something really basic.

But what?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, five minutes later I have an answer. I'm going to post this here in case someone else has the same problem, even though it makes me look really stupid.

Short version: it *is* that five-year old bug I found. It's just that the version of wxWidgets on Debian, which I'm developing on, is so old it hasn't picked up the bugfix.

The good news is that wxWidgets 3.2, which does have the bugfix, is being packaged right now (last post August 28 2022: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=919903). But I don't think that'll help me much, so I'll need to find a workaround. At least now I know what's going on.

Comment: you can try to compile the latest version yourself and see if the problem is resolved.